# Android Volley: Put request not updating any data

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

i'm trying to update some data with android volley but not working. and with postman it works.

**my code:**

```
private void aceptarAlerta()
{
    mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getmRequestQueue();
    SharedPreferences preferencia = getSharedPreferences("ComuniUsuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    token = preferencia.getString("ComuniToken", null);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Respuesta: ", response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("estado", "true");
            params.put("cuidador", Tmensaje[2]);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Token " + token);
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
            return new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    15000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        }

    };
    mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

and if i delete params from code i dont get any error response from server.

i don't know what's the problem, i think have a logical error.

Comment: dont you have to put execute or something like mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest).execute();?

Comment: i get an error with .execute()

Comment: Can you please post the error response you are getting?

Comment: @Toguard i don't get any error response but i get  a "success" response:**{"usuario":"poyo99","fecha_creacion":"2016-01-22T17:59:44.782139Z","estado":false,"cuidador":"poyo"}** but any data is updating

Comment: Then I would say debug your service. The response should not be successful and not update the resource. Perhaps the service is somehow returning the same instance by either cached memory (handling two different instances) or failing and still reporting success with the same resource you wanted to modify.
It can also be that the parameters are different between http client you are using.